# Open new terminal and read input in Node.js

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a bunch of microservices and I use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to start/monitor/etc.
In one of the microservices I need to decrypt a private key using a password that I should read it from terminal. I can't do that with pm2.

Can you help me with a recomandation, how I can implement this functionality ?
I need to keep the pm2, but I can do other things for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why You can't do that with `pm2`? While starting script via `pm2` you can `Pass extra arguments to the script` i think it can be your password.

And why you `should read it from terminal`, why not save password to file, and next read it via `fs` module in node?

**UPDATE**

Maybe pass args via `--node-args` like:
`pm2 start server.js --node-args="--password=secretPass"`

Comment: Can't read it from a file, it should stay only in memory.

Comment: ok, so you can pass it like `pm2 server.js --node-args="--password=verySecretPass"`